# How should I load my own training data into this Generative Adversarial Network?

Tags: python

I'm an absolute beginner with Python. Recently, I loaded the MNIST handwritten digit database into a Generative Adversarial Network. The program runs fine but I want to know how to modify the code below so I can load my own training data, a folder of JPGs, instead of the MNIST database. Is there an easy way to do this with this code?

I understand that I need to convert the images into MNIST format but beyond that I don't understand which lines I would have to include and/or edit to load the folder.

Thanks for helping out!

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras import initializers
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "tensorflow"
np.random.seed(10)
random_dim = 100
def load_minst_data():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train = (x_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5)/127.5
    x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
    return (x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)
def get_optimizer():
        return Adam(lr=0.0002, beta_1=0.5)
def get_generator(optimizer):
        generator = Sequential()
        generator.add(Dense(256, input_dim=random_dim, 
kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.02)))
        generator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
        generator.add(Dense(512))
        generator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
        generator.add(Dense(1024))
        generator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
        generator.add(Dense(784, activation='tanh'))
        generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
        return generator
def get_discriminator(optimizer):
        discriminator = Sequential()
        discriminator.add(Dense(1024, input_dim=784, 
kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.02)))
        discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
        discriminator.add(Dropout(0.3))
        discriminator.add(Dense(512))
        discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
        discriminator.add(Dropout(0.3))
        discriminator.add(Dense(256))
        discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))
        discriminator.add(Dropout(0.3))
        discriminator.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
        discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
       return discriminator
def get_gan_network(discriminator, random_dim, generator, optimizer):
        discriminator.trainable = False
        gan_input = Input(shape=(random_dim,))
        x = generator(gan_input)
        gan_output = discriminator(x)
        gan = Model(inputs=gan_input, outputs=gan_output)
        gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
        return gan
def plot_generated_images(epoch, generator, examples=100, dim=(10, 10), 
figsize=(10, 10)):
        noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=[examples, random_dim])
        generated_images = generator.predict(noise)
        generated_images = generated_images.reshape(examples, 28, 28)
        plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
        for i in range(generated_images.shape[0]):
                plt.subplot(dim[0], dim[1], i+1)
                plt.imshow(generated_images[i], interpolation='nearest', cmap='gray_r')
                plt.axis('off')
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.savefig('gan_generated_image_epoch_%d.png' % epoch)
def train(epochs=1, batch_size=128):
         x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = load_minst_data()
         batch_count = x_train.shape[0] // batch_size
         adam = get_optimizer()
         generator = get_generator(adam)
         discriminator = get_discriminator(adam)
         gan = get_gan_network(discriminator, random_dim, generator, adam)
         for e in range(1, epochs+1):
                 print ('-'*15, 'Epoch %d' % e, '-'*15)
                 for _ in tqdm(range(batch_count)):
                         noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=[batch_size, random_dim])
                         image_batch = x_train[np.random.randint(0, x_train.shape[0], size=batch_size)]
                         generated_images = generator.predict(noise)
                         X = np.concatenate([image_batch, generated_images])
                         y_dis = np.zeros(2*batch_size)
                         y_dis[:batch_size] = 0.9
                         discriminator.trainable = True
                         discriminator.train_on_batch(X, y_dis)
                         noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=[batch_size, random_dim])
                         y_gen = np.ones(batch_size)
                         discriminator.trainable = False
                         gan.train_on_batch(noise, y_gen)
                 if e == 1 or e % 20 == 0:
                         plot_generated_images(e, generator)
if __name__ == '__main__':
         train(400, 128)
```

Answer (score 0):

[MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) is a dataset rather than a format.

The following line is where the code author loads the dataset:

```
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = load_minst_data()
```

In:

```
def train(epochs=1, batch_size=128):
         x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = load_minst_data()
         ...
```

This calls the function:

```
def load_minst_data():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train = (x_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5)/127.5
    x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
    return (x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)
```

Which you could modify to load your dataset.

Also, since the code expects four variables for `x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test` respectively in:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

I suggest using [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). The function will help you split your data into the aforementioned variables.

The following line:

```
x_train = (x_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5)/127.5
```

[Normalizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)) the training samples.

And in:

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
```

The author is flattening `60000` samples into one vector of size `784` in order to feed them to the model.

P. S. It is possible to reshape into `784` because MNIST is, originally,  `28x28` pixels.

You will also need to modify your data shapes or change the `input_dim` in:

```
discriminator.add(Dense(1024, input_dim=784,kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.02)))
```

And *probably* each existence of `784`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation of this beast, Andrew! Much appreciated.